Pauses in the middle of "align" in beamer
When using the beamer documentclass, normally one writes:
\begin{frame}

blab blah blah

\pause

blah blah blah

\end{frame}

One one of these pages I have a display like this:
\begin{align*}
& a \\
= {} & b \\
= {} & c \\
= {} & d \\
= {} & e
\end{align*}

I would like to put a \pause between two lines of this, and have the alignment of "equals" signs before and after the \pause make sense.
Can that be done?

Please add a short, but compilable test file which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a document environment.

"normally one writes": \pause is a very crude command and I would avoid it whenever possible. Other overlay macros allow much more find control.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Specifically what other macros?

macros like \only<>{...}, \visible<>{...} etc.

To quote the beamer user guide:

[\pause] does not work inside amsmath environments like align, since these do really wicked things.

The beamer user guide also shows on page 213 how to uncover an align environment instead:
\documentclass{beamer}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{align*}
& a \\
= {} & b \\
\uncover<2->{= {} & c \\}
\uncover<2->{= {} & d \\}
\uncover<2->{= {} & e \\}
\notag
\end{align*}

\end{frame}

\end{document}


